# Regular expression to identify first character only

Tags: regex

I'm trying to identify medical diagnosis codes that start with either 8 or 9, without regard to what comes afterwards.  They might be formatted as 800.1, 956.35, etc.

Our programmer got me started with [89][0-9][0-9]* but that appears to be identifying anything with an 8 or 9 in it.

Dividing the searches up would be fine.  I tried using a simple ^[8], ^8, ^[9], ^9, and all of those found 800 in the tester (I'm using regexpal.com)...but nothing else (it didn't find 850, etc).

Thanks!

Comment: add an anchor `^[89]` matches string starting with 8 or 9

Comment: Is the decimal point always there, and is it always a single decimal place?  How many digits are possible before the decimal place?

Comment: Did you enable the _`^$ match at line breaks (m)`_ option on regexpal.com?

Comment: Thanks!  I'm getting different responses in another tester - looks like this is going to work.  Much appreciated!

Comment: And I did not have that enabled - d'oh!  Working there now, too.  Thank you!

Comment: Also see this shorted regex: http://regex101.com/r/iW0vC3/1

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you already a regex guru, I will answer just pro forma.

Just use a `^[89]` regular expression to only match strings that start with `8` or `9`.

Here, `^` is an anchor that tells the regex engine to match at the beginning of a string (or line if `multiline` option is enabled, or `(?m)` is added at the beginning of the regex pattern).

`[89]` is a non-negated character class that will match every character inside it (or a range, if the range is provided).

A [demo](http://regex101.com/r/iW0vC3/1) has been provided by msrd0.